# how can i get menu outside from the table? i attached the image with this question for better clarification

Tags: html, css, angular

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfqzb.png) just want menu outside from the table. i used z-index and every possible way.

[Click on this link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P77EJ.jpg)

```
.dropdown-parent {
position: relative;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown-panel {
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid #2f6f98;
border-radius: 0.25rem;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
margin-top: 38px;
width: 190px;
z-index: 9;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
color: #2f6f98;
}
```

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxCXX.png) Below is my sample html code. i removed my data binding. just look in this and help me out.

```
<td colspan="2">
    <div class="dropdown-parent">
        <div class="tooltipSEC">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="numOfRate availableBtn">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
            <!-- tooltip -->
            <div class="tooltiptext">
                <ul>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- tooltip -->
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-panel">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <h4 class="title">{{'Resource' | translate}}</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs" (click)="addResourceToLine(line,resource)" [disabled]="line.disabled">{{'Set' | translate}}</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your container (propably your table itself) has not set `overflow: hidden` but for example `overflow: visible`

Comment: i just want when click on arrow button menu should be display outside not inside. right now it is going inside.

Comment: first of all your posted code is not full, your `addResourceToLine(line,resource)` does something... propably adds this container with menu. If you want element to be posted outside the table, you need to add element outside the table and then position it based on element coordinates -> below that element that was clicked perhaps.

Comment: Right but i have so much value coming from back-end so that's why i'm using table.

Comment: thats not the point. You didn't attach your html how you fill your data and you didn't attach function body of `addResourceToLine`. What do you want to achive ? Does your menu needs to be outside the table because is unvisible(the `overflow could fix that) or is there other reason why you dont want menu to be inside the table ?

Comment: bro consider it as dummy. i added everything except my angular binding part. i'm asking about simple html and css relation question not about angular related question.

Comment: why do you want to have virtually the data to be outside the table ? Why overflow approach is bad ?

Comment: Yes I can see, it is cutted... Do you know why its cutted ? Propably because your table has overflow:hidden

Comment: I'm not using any overflow : hidden property because as one more date will come the table will grow automatically.

Comment: Try to add to from your container(that keeps dropdown) to up fathers the property `overflow:visible`.